# Why I cannot get the selected row index from JTable even though there's selection occurred?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have here class `EmployeeList` with extends of `JFrame` and the other one is `NewJFrame` with extends of `JFrame`.

Now in `EmployeeList` class it has a `JTable` component and button. The constructor in `NewJFrame` class has a code like this:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    EmployeeList frm1 = new EmployeeList();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, frm1.jTable1.getSelectedRow());
}
```

The button component from `EmployeeList` has action event and the code is like this:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     NewJFrame frm = new NewJFrame();
     frm.setVisible(true);
}
```

Note: I already set the `JTable` from `EmployeeList` class to public but the return value of selected row index is always -1. I called here the class `EmployeeList` first and after that I selected one row from the table and after that I clicked the button.

Can someone explain to me? Or how can I achieve that?

Comment: What makes you so sure a row is in fact selected? Does the EmployeeList class select a row for you as well?

Comment: This looks like some very faulty design to me. You have also not given us too much too work with. How is the GUI started? What is called first? You should provide more code (ideally a [mre]), because right now the only thing we can say is: You have some weird circular dependency between the `EmployeeList` and `NewJFrame`. Think about it, a button press in your `EmployeeList` instance (*Instance A*) will create a new `NewJFrame`, and in the constructor of `NewJFrame()` you create a new instance of `EmployeeList` (*Instance B*). Fixing this, will also fix the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) Give classes (attributes and methods) *meaningful*, descriptive names. E.G. while `EmployeeList` is a good name, `NewJFrame` is ..not. If it had been called `EditEmployee` instead, as an example, it might suggest the best path to follow to avoid multiple frames. A (possibly modal) `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` would be good for that.

Comment: BTW - in this code.. `EmployeeList frm1 = new EmployeeList(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, frm1.jTable1.getSelectedRow());` note that `frm1` is not the frame in which a selection was made. It is probably not even visible on-screen. It will **always** fail to show any user selection.